# Helper method renders no list items

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 7, why the following helper doesn't render the list items?

```
def list(options)
  tag.ul(class: "a") do
    options.each do |option|
      tag.li(class: "b") do
        tag.span(option, class: "c")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I call `<%= list(["X", "Y", "Z"]) %>` and what is rendered is simply  `<ul class="a"></ul>`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, with erb you'd write this:

```rb
<%= tag.ul(class: "a") do %>
  <% ["X", "Y", "Z"].each do |option| %>
    <%= tag.li(class: "b") do %>         # <%= %> is the same as `concat`
      <%= tag.span(option, class: "c") %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Using [`concat`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat):

```rb
def list(options)
  tag.ul(class: "a") do
    options.each do |option|
      concat(
        tag.li(class: "b") do
          # concat could be omitted here for a single tag
          concat tag.span(option, class: "c")
        end
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Using [`safe_join`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-safe_join):

```rb
def list(options)
  tag.ul(class: "a") do
    safe_join(
      options.map do |option|
        tag.li(class: "b") do
          tag.span(option, class: "c")
        end
      end
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `concat` does the trick.

Comment: @engineersmnky technically you don't need `=` there, i was just trying to show where `concat` would be absolutely necessary in the helper.

Comment: @Alex I was unaware that we could forgo the `=` and still have it render through ERB; however after some [Testing](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/LiquidInferiorDegree#main.rb) it appears you are correct. Learned something new. Feel free to revert the change as you see fit.

Comment: @engineersmnky tag builder is using `capture` helper which either gives you value in the output buffer or return value of the block.